# Getting notified in another browser when a chat message is sent in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am sending messages in using Twilio using this code:

```
string channelId = <channelId>;
string serviceSid = <servicesid>;
IpMessagingClient ipMessagingClient = new IpMessagingClient(<accountid>, <token>);
var msgResult = ipMessagingClient.CreateMessage(serviceSid, channelId, "sender", "message");

msg.Body = "body"
msg.DateSent = DateTime.Now;
msg.Sender = "sender"

return Json(new
{
    Success = msgResult.Sid != null,
    NewMessage = msg
});
```

Message is sent just fine and I can retrieve the messages of the channel. What I am trying to achieve now is other open browser and in the channel gets notified of new messages sent so I can update the UI to display the new messages without manual refreshing the browser.

Comment: Using the JS SDK, you'll need to use `channel.on('messageAdded', function() {})` to subscribe to a message listener. This would perhaps update a count for the channel, or add the message text to a chat body.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are using the REST API to send messages to the Programmable Chat API.

To get using the client versions, the JS client in particular, I would take a read through the [Programmable Chat documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat), go download the [JS SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/sdks) and take a look at [the code for the reference chat demo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-js). All of those bits should give you a good grounding in building chat for the client side.

Let me know if that helps at all.